# Calling a method in a fragment from a separate class

Tags: android, fragment, android-context

What's the best way to call a method inside a fragment from a different class? I passed the context via `getActivity()` into the class. Something along the lines of

`((Fragment) ((Activity) context).getMainFragment()).Method();`

This just doesn't look right....

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

Create interface `OnMyDialogClickListener` and class `MyDialogFragment`, which will call methods of created interface

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
```

```
private OnMyDialogClickListener listener;

public static DialogFragment newInstance(OnMyDialogClickListener listener) {
    DialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment(listener);
    return fragment;
}

private MyDialogFragment(OnMyDialogClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new DialogButtonsClickListener);
    return dialog
}

private final class DialogButtonsClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       listener.Method();
    }
}

public static interface OnMyDialogClickListener {

    void Method();

}
```

}

Implement interface in your target fragment:

```
public class AlbumsFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnMyDialogClickListener {

    .....

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //show dialog
        DialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(this);
        myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), ALBUM_ACTION_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void Method() {
         //some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what are you doing.

If the operation was issued from a Fragment, you should pass a Fragment instance to a class or method that does it.

If that's an event like "user logged out" or "sdcard removed" you should send a local broadcast and register a BroadcastReceiver in the Fragment.

Comment: Could the class define an interface from the activity? Then pass the implementation into it?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods I use frequently:

```
//#1 interface method in turn calls fragment;
((SomeInteraceOrSuperClass) getActivity).intefaceMethod();


//#2 hashmap = fragment directory;
TitleFrag titlefrag = (TitleFrag) getActivity().m_mapFrags.get(KEY_TITLEFRAG);
titleFrag.method();
```

Answer (score 0):

This way -> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html (interfaces and magic)

Please, check android developers often. It contains many awnsers on good pratices.